# If you consider a BST containing N nodes that has height h, what is the worst case the number of compares to Hibbard delete a key?

Tags: java, algorithm, comparison, binary-search-tree

I thought it was just h compares, but a classmate thinks that it is h + 1. Help please?

This is the code for deletion in BST if anyone needs to see.

```
public void deleteMin()
{
    root = deleteMin(root);
}
private Node deleteMin(Node x)
{
    if (x.left == null) return x.right;
    x.left = deleteMin(x.left);
    x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
    return x;
}
public void delete(Key key)
{ root = delete(root, key); }
private Node delete(Node x, Key key)
{
    if (x == null) return null;
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if (cmp < 0) x.left = delete(x.left, key);
    else if (cmp > 0) x.right = delete(x.right, key);
    else
    {
        if (x.right == null) return x.left;
        if (x.left == null) return x.right;
       Node t = x;
        x = min(t.right); // See page 407.
        x.right = deleteMin(t.right);
        x.left = t.left;
    }
    x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: What is Hibbard deletion?

Comment: @templatetypedef I didn't know either but this link has good psuedocode for understanding it: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/9-BinTree/BST-delete2.html